# JavaScript Parsing Data into an Object

Tags: javascript, html, csv

interesting question for you. I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse information from my `.csv` file so that I have the raw data and can make comparisons.

What I'm trying to do right now is make an object for each person from the data that gets parsed in. So my csv file consists of:

```
Position,Name,Salary,Gender,Category
Chef,John Doe,40000,M,0
Clerk,Jane Doe,20000,F,1
Server,Joe Doe,30000,M,2
```

That's a very minor portion, I have towards 1000 different people, where obviously positions and such repeat. In my code, I currently have the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
  var lines;
  var person;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    //fetch text file
    $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
      //split on new lines
      lines = data.split('\n');

      //This line didn't work and gave me an error? 
      //person = lines.split(',');

      person = data.split(',');

                //window.alert(lines[1]);
                //window.alert(person[5]);

    });

  });

</script>
```

Anyways, I basically have tried a few things, didn't work and deleted it. So let me go over what I have tried.

1. Each line works correctly, so line currently gives out the entire line by line. So I tried to then split each of those lines into player based off of `,`. This however gave me an error saying that `.split` is undefined.
2. So next thing I tried was just splitting from the data, and that works to some degree. It splits perfectly for the first line, then gets wonky when it comes to the new line. It skips the position `chef` and takes `John Doe`. Then when it gets to the `Category` it correctly takes `0` but also prints out `Chef` with 2 enters below it in the same window when using `window.alert(var[number])`

Then I realize, well this isn't really going to work anyways, I want to make each person it's own object. So I want every `person` to have it's own variables: `position, name, salary, gender, category`

I looked that up and I get quite a few ways of how to make it, but none take the information in through a file but manually define it right then and there. So is there some way that someone can help me with this? Do I have to do some kind of for loop, and then something interesting like:

```
var people = {
  position:"",
  name:"",
  salary:0,
  gender:"",
  category:,
};

for(i = 5; i != eof; i+5){
  people.position() = person[i];
  people.name() = person[i+1];
  people.salary() = person[i+2];
  people.gender() = person[i+3];
  people.category() = person[i+4];
}
```

Honestly not too sure, so any help with this would be great. Thanks!

---

Edit:
With the assistance of Lucas, this is where I'm currently at:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">


          var people = [];

           $(document).ready(function() {
             $.get('data.csv', function(data){

               var lines = data.split('\n');
               var properties = ["position", "name", "salary", "points", "team"]

               for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                 var person = lines[i].split(',');
                 var tmpPlayer = {}
                 for (var n = 0; n < person.length; n++){
                   tmpPlayer[properties[n]] = person[n]
                 }
                 people.push(tmpPlayer);
               }

             });

            //correctly displays the array of every person
            console.log(people);
            //gives the result undefined
            console.log(people[1]);
            //error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
            console.log(people[1]["name"]);

           });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `data.csv` file:

```
Position,Name,Salary,Gender,Category
Chef,John Doe,40000,M,0
Clerk,Jane Doe,20000,F,1
Server,Joe Doe,30000,M,2
```

Comment: lines is an array not a string so you can't split it. You have to iterate through *each* element in lines and split this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines` is an array not a string so you can't split it. You have to iterate through each element in `lines` and split this instead.

```
  var people = [];
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //fetch text file
    $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
      //split on new lines
      var lines = data.split('\n');

      //This line didn't work and gave me an error? 
      //person = lines.split(',');

      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
          var person = lines[i].split(',');
          var tmpPerson = 
           {
             position = person[0];
             name = person[1];
             salary = person[2];
             gender = person[3];
             category = person[4];
           }
           people.push(tmpPerson);

        }

                //window.alert(lines[1]);
                //window.alert(person[5]);

    });

  });
```

If you want to dynamically assign the properties to each object you can loop over the properties instead of hardcoding them, as long as you have defined them as array somewhere.

```js
var data = 
 `Chef,John Doe,40000,M,0
 Clerk,Jane Doe,20000,F,1
 Server,Joe Doe,30000,M,2`
  
      var people = [];
      $(document).ready(function() {

          var lines = data.split('\n');
       var properties = ["position", "name", "salary", "gender", "category"]
          //This line didn't work and gave me an error? 
          //person = lines.split(',');
    
          for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                  var person = lines[i].split(',');
        var tmpPerson = {};
        for (var n = 0; n<person.length; n++){
       tmpPerson[properties[n]] = person[n];
        }
               people.push(tmpPerson);
    
            }
            console.log(people)
    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are using a query to retrieve data from your file then you have to put your logging/rendering in a separate function that you call upon the completion of the `$.get` query (or within the `$.get`query itself). JavaScript runs these queries asynchronously so you were logging the result of `people` before any values were pushed to `people`. The below implementation should solve your issue. It seems that you are just getting started on your adventure with js so I recommend some reading on this: https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


          var people = [];

           $(document).ready(function() {
             $.get('data.csv', function(data){

               var lines = data.split('\n');
               var properties = ["position", "name", "salary", "points", "team"]

               for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                 var person = lines[i].split(',');
                 var tmpPlayer = {}
                 for (var n = 0; n < person.length; n++){
                   tmpPlayer[properties[n]] = person[n]
                 }
                 people.push(tmpPlayer);
               }
               alert(people[1]["name"]);
               render();
             });



           });


           function render(){
             alert(people[1].name);
           }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh wow, silly me... Yes this makes a lot of sense. Now is there some way to incorporate the object that I mentioned through this? Would it be something as silly as my for loop at the end of my question (just iterating through the lines array first to split that).

Comment: Also when I added your for loop, I'm getting undefined for when I .alert person[0]

Comment: you could implement a loop but then your object properties would no longer carry the names you want them to carry unless you had a separate properties array that you could map to each.

Comment: Just checking, I would have to define the people object above/outside of the function (like in my question) correct?

Comment: Yes...I added this to my answer. I use an array

Comment: Just to check and make sure all worked out as intended, how do I alert, or print out. So like when I did: `window.alert(people[0])` I got `undefined` as the output

Comment: Outside of the entire `$(document) function` I placed: `window.alert(people[0]);` and `window.alert(people[1]);` (so right before the `</script>`) and both had the output: `undefined`. Is the way I'm calling people wrong? like should it be `people.name`?

The console gave me back no errors. I'm not entirely sure how to manually debug other than that.

Comment: I have updated my answer to contain a snippet which appears to be logging correctly.

Comment: You cannot log outside of the document.ready function because that log function is going to get called before you do any operation as the document gets loaded *after* the script executes. You need to do all logging in document.ready function to see the right values

Comment: Yeah I'm using your second code, the dynamically set one. I just did the same thing with logging the people array and works the exact same as yours. I was just testing specifically, so I wanted to call on the first person (so technically people[1] (since person[0] is just the titles)) and if I try to log with `console.log(people[0]["name"]);` it gives back the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: did you try my new answer? seems to work on plnkr for me

Comment: Yeah that did it for me. The code should have been `people[num].property` and I was doing another `[property]`... Thanks so much for your assistance~

Comment: that was not your issue....you could do either! Please read my answer fully to understand what was tripping you up.

Answer (score 0):

`lines = data.split('\n');` returns an array. So, when you then write `person = lines.split(',');` it's going to fail because you are now trying to call `.split` on an array, not a string. You'd want something like this: `person = lines[0].split(',');` and you need another loop to dig into each person.

```js
  var data = 
`Chef,John Doe,40000,M,0
 Clerk,Jane Doe,20000,F,1
 Server,Joe Doe,30000,M,2`
  
  var lines = null;
  var person = null;

  $(function() {
    
      //split on new lines
      lines = data.split('\n');

      var len = lines.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        person = lines[i].split(',');

        var l2 = person.length;
        for(var x = 0; x < l2; ++x){
          console.log(person[x]);
        } 
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```